# Counting characters in string

Tags: arrays, c, string

my problem seems quite easy but I can't work out what's wrong with it. My program is supposed to count how many times each number from 1 to 9 occur in a text with mixed letters and numbers, but apparently, all it does is printing nine zeros. I checked if my function gets the string correctly and it went fine so I'm really confused with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char a[1000];

    fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);

    int tab1[9] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int tab[9];
    int num1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(a); j++)
        {
            if (a[j] == tab1[i])
            {
                num1 += 1;
            }
        }
        tab[i] = num1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", tab[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone would help me find the problem.

Comment: Still reading through your code, but I can already tell you that you need to reset num1 after checking for each number. Otherwise it will continue counting up across all numbers.

Comment: Did you get a string? Print out a and strlen(a) to test, if fgets got the string you expected...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main issue here is that you are comparing characters to integers, as `a` is an array of characters whereas `tab1` is an array of integers. Characters and integers cannot be compared to each other in the way you are doing. In order to fix this, declare `tab1` as

```
char tab1[9] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
```

You also need to set num1 to 0 after each loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the tab1 array being type integer. Your code is comparing a character from array a with an integer from array tab1.

For the comparison to occur, you want to declare tab1 as an array of strings, containing the digits you want to measure in terms of frequency.

Here's my solution, you'll notice three things:

1. I declare tab as an array of chars, not integers.
2. I prefill tab1 to avoid the num variable, making the code cleaner.
3. I skip entering the explicit size of all arrays, leaving this job to the compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char a[1000];
    fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);

    char* tab1[] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
    int tab[] =  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (int)strlen(a); j++)
        {
            if(a[j] == *tab1[i])
            {
                tab[i] += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", tab[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned *countDigits(const char *str, unsigned *freqTable)
{
    static const char digits[] = "0123456789";
    const char *pos;

    if(freqTable) memset(freqTable, 0, 10 * sizeof(*freqtable));
    if(str)
    {
        while(*str)
        {
            if((pos = strchr(digits, *str++)))
            {
                freqTable[pos - digits]++;
            }
        }        
    }
    return freqTable;
}
```

Comment: My purely personal opinion: the `if (freqTable)` and `if (str)` is unnecessary clutter. If the programmer by mistake doesn't provide valid pointers to the function, it is better to crash than continue as if nothing happened.